# How to get/store last SENT messenger bot message to a user?

Tags: chatbot, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-chatbot

If a user replies with a normal text message to the bot, what would be the best way to know what happened earlier? As i have seen, the bot can't get this information from the graph api and i guess that would be the slowest option. So a dictionary or store it in database or any other idea?
(in my case i use python but i think it doesn't matter in this case)

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do something similar and ended up creating a basic API backend to store answers. This was using Node.js and MongoDB but Python and MongoDB should work just as well.

If you're looking to just play around a little, mLab offers a free sandbox option that pairs easily with Heroku.

mLab: https://mlab.com/

Heroku connection information: https://elements.heroku.com/addons/mongolab

Hope that helps a little.